# Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt in openstack vm

Tags: kernel, openstack, kvm, panic

[image: error snapshot]I setup openstack in one ubuntu server and allocated several vms in the openstack. randomly some vms are panic w/ the error(see below). Anyone can give some suggestions? thanks

Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
build_skb
__netdev_alloc_skb
page_to_skb
kvm_clock_get_cycles
virtnet_poll
net_rx_action
__do_softirq
irq_exit
do_irq
common_interrupt
native_safe_halt
default_idle
arch_cpu_idle
cpu_startup_entry
start_secondary

Comment: have you checked the memory usage of your vm guests and your physical host?

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem on a VPS from OVH.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something like this in Openstack when I was programming Kernel modules. It occurred because there were logical faults in my Kernel code. Any time this happened I had to shut off the instance and start it again. I then debugged my kernel code and corrected the fault. But I have no idea if you have been programming Kernel modules or not.

Alternatively, if you are not programming Kernel modules, the image you are using to create your instances may be corrupt or configured incorrectly.

Not sure if this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: My knowledge in this area is limited to my personal experience of installing Ubuntu and not actual expertise]

I believe I also faced something similar when I was trying to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox (Windows 11).

1. Go to settings and type "core isolation"
2. Here you'll find a setting called "Memory Integrity", turn it off

[ Just a word of caution: Microsoft says that enabling this setting might help with device security.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/core-isolation-e30ed737-17d8-42f3-a2a9-87521df09b78

But this wasn't enabled by default (windows defender prompted me to enable this setting a while before I encountered this problem, so I tried disabling it, and it worked for me) ]

[memory integrity setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmitd.png)

Then go to VirtualBox to remove and recreate the virtual machine